# jQuery slideshow customisation

Tags: jquery

The following slideshow works well, however by I adding a data-attribute on each img tag I would like to change the background color of the body to match the background of each image.

How can I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/L62Ja/12/

```
            $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                                    // data attribute to change the body bg color
                    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSfiddle is throwing up an error, so it's hard to pinpoint this exactly. Hopefully this gets you on your way.

After it calculates the $next slide, it has to grab that slide's data attribute, like this:

`var $bgcolor = $($next).data("color");`

Then it has to apply that as a CSS element to the body upon animation completion, like this:

`$("body").addClass($bgcolor);`

If you get your jsfiddle working, I can work on this more, but this should at least get you on your way.

Comment: Hi there, i Fixed it http://jsfiddle.net/L62Ja/12/, I now have a little problem the body background color seems to fadeIn before the image creating a not nice effect. I have also changed the values of the data attributes to match the img bg color

Comment: I just moved your `addcolor` function to run after the animation... and I added in some placeholder images so I could actually see what was going on. And finally, I added a CSS `transition` to the background color so it's not so jarring when it changes. Is this what you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/L62Ja/13/